# Bizzarre behavior of pgfkeys' first char syntax detection

Tags: pgfkeys

I saved the following code in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
   precision/.code={precision=#1},
   unit/.code={unit=#1},
   /handlers/first char syntax=true,
   /handlers/first char syntax/the character 0/.initial=\Precision,
   /handlers/first char syntax/the letter a/.initial=\Unit
}

\def\Precision#1{\pgfkeysalso{precision=#1}}
\def\Unit#1{\pgfkeysalso{unit=#1}}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{0}

\end{document}
```

The code configures the `\pgfkeys` command to inspect the first character of each key, and if this character is the digit `0`, or the letter `a`, to call the the `\Precision`, resp. `\Unit` command, with a single argument: the key. The `\Precision` command expands to the string "precision=#1", where #1 is its argument, and similarly the `\Unit` command expands to "unit=#1". The code then calls `\pgfkeys`, passing it the key `0` (i.e. the digit zero).

Then I executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> pdflatex Test
```

Consequently the file `~/Test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer it displayed the string "precision=0", as expected.

I then changed the code in the following way. I replaced the string`the letter a` by the string`the letter p`. I then recompiled. The generated PDF file now displayed the string "unit=precision".

This caught me by surprise. I expected the outcome of the second compilation to be the same as the outcome of the first compilation, since the argument to the `\pgfkeys` command that's in the document's body hasn't changed, and it is neither `a` nor `p`.

Furthermore, I don't understand how the string "unit" came to be on the right hand side of the equality symbol.

**Questions**

1. Why did the second compilation not produce the string "precision=0" as the first compilation had done?
2. Why did the second compilation produce the string "unit=precision"?

Comment: well you have `\pgfkeysalso{precision=#1}}` which starts with p so you stop that acting as a normal key

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I see. Why, then, isn't the output of the second compilation "unit=precision=0"?

Comment: presumably it splits on =first.. But the whole construct is so weird I can't guess what you really want to do here. Also it will fail for any non ascii characters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to be able to pass the options `[2, cm]` instead of `[precision=2, unit=cm]`.

Comment: why not simply declare keys 2 and cm instead of breaking every key that happens to start with c ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't understand the question. I want to write a command that has two optional arguments that are independent of each other: *precision*, and *unit*. (Independent in the sense that each of them can be provided without the other, or both can be provided simultaneously, or both can be dropped.) I'd like to be able to write them in any order.

Comment: sure but you could declare a key `cm` that sets the unit, why disable every key starting with  c (or as in the question disable every key starting p)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My command has only two optional arguments: *precision* and *unit*. *Precision* takes a numeric argument, whereas *unit* takes an alphabetic argument from the ASCII alphabet. I was going to set a `first char syntax` handler for every one of the 10 digits, and for every one of the 26 lowercase letters of the English alphabet.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `.unknown` handler to check those “keys” whether they are a number (e.g. start with digit, `.`, `+` or `-`) or not, those are units. Though, it would be much easier just to define keys for the units and treat everything else that's unknown as the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on [David Carlisle's advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668573/bizzarre-behavior-of-pgfkeys-first-char-syntax-detection#comment1662094_668573). I got the list of TeX dimensions from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/TeX_dimensions). I only need the six precision values 0 to 5.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
   /stripdim/.cd,
   precision/.value required,
   precision/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{/stripdim/precision}{#1}[precision=#1]},
   unit/.value required,
   unit/.initial=cm,
   unit/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{/stripdim/unit}{#1}[unit=#1]},
   pt/.style={unit=pt},
   pc/.style={unit=pc},
   bp/.style={unit=bp},
   in/.style={unit=in},
   cm/.style={unit=cm},
   mm/.style={unit=mm},
   dd/.style={unit=dd},
   cc/.style={unit=cc},
   sp/.style={unit=sp},
   ex/.style={unit=ex},
   em/.style={unit=em},
   fil/.style={unit=fil},
   fill/.style={unit=fill},
   filll/.style={unit=filll},
   0/.style={precision=0},
   1/.style={precision=1},
   2/.style={precision=2},
   3/.style={precision=3},
   4/.style={precision=4},
   5/.style={precision=5}
}

\newcommand{\stripdim}[1][]{%
   \pgfkeys{/stripdim/.cd,#1}%
}

\begin{document}

[\stripdim]\par
\stripdim[precision=3]\par
\stripdim[unit=cm]\par
\stripdim[precision=3,unit=cm]\par
\stripdim[unit=cm,precision=3]\par
\stripdim[3]\par
\stripdim[cm]\par
\stripdim[3,cm]\par
\stripdim[cm,3]\par

\end{document}
```

[image: Using pgfkeys to infer the keys.]

Comment: `precision/.style={precision/.initial=#1},` is weird. Just give it an initial, say `precision/.initial=0` and after that all `precision=<num>` just store `<num>` in that key. No need to re`.initial`ize.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The `precision` key is not supposed to have an initial value. It is supposed to indicate the number of places after the decimal point, but if it isn't specified, the number of places after the decimal point is whatever happens to be the case.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Also: I did it this way for the sake of this example, in order to be able both to set a key's value as well as have it perform a command (in this case, print something). Normally when a key performs a command, it doesn't store a value, and vice versa.

Comment: `precision/.initial=` would be valid, too. It might be easier to test against an empty value than an undefined one. But of course this will all depend on your project and how it should work. Re second point. Yes. But maybe just `precision/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/stripdim/precision}{#1}, precision/.append code=<stuff>` would be a clearer (and faster) indication on what's going on.